# Login authenticate at each page jsp/servlet

Tags: java, servlets

I am creating an application that will have multiple pages in it, I want a user to be redirect to login page in case he isn't authenticated already and tries to access some intermediate page.

I am developing this on jsp/servlet, but struts can be considered as well.

Comment: you need HttpSession and Filter for login authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ServletFilter` will help you intercept requests and check for user login status -- here's a good article : http://www.developer.com/security/article.php/3467801/Securing-J2EE-Applications-with-a-Servlet-Filter.htm

Answer (score 0):

While you are logging in, set a Session attribute

```
request.setAttribute("user","<username>");
```

and in each and every page, at first check the session attribute whether its set,

```
String user=request.getAttribute("user");
//check in database for user
if(<user not exist>){
 response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
}
```

Comment: this is something that i used to do and dont want this again... it has to be implemented on each and every page.... and is not done at application level

Answer (score 0):

You can use either container-based security or form-based security to authenticate users. With container-based security, the Web browser will track the logins for you, and "replay" the credentials to the server whenever they are required. If a browser hasn't been authenticated yet, it will automatically display a simple login form. If the login passes, the user's original request will proceed. This will also work properly if a user tried to POST from a form to an action URI in a protected area. Once the browser is authenticated, the POST proceeds normally. For applications that manage their own logins, it is probably easier to insist that every single page test for an authenticated user first, and redirect to the login page if not. The Struts example application does this -- partially by use of an application-specific custom tag (app:checkLogon) that performs this check at the top of every page. The tag is application-specific, because the notion of what constitutes a "logged on user" is application specific as well.

Also below link will help you more

http://www.mooreds.com/jaas.html

You might want to extend RequestProcessor.It is one of the best practices.It is amazing what you can do in it's method.Look into it's processPreprocess method.

For more info refer...
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2004/jw-0913-struts-p2.html